# Why double click DataGridView makes DataGriView like it becomes a filter in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, datagridview

Why double click  DataGridView makes DataGriView like it becomes a filter in vb.net?
should load full at the time of double clicking datagridview what there might be something wrong with my code.
the datagridview in my code uses nuget packages "Kimtoo.Bindingprovider"
Thanks

```
Private record As TEST
Private Sub LoadData()
        Try
            Dim data As List(Of TEST) = Con.Query(Of TEST)("Select * From TEST").ToList()
             DataGridView1.Bind(data)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
Private Sub DataGridView1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DoubleClick
        Me.record = DirectCast(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Tag, TEST)
        BindingProvider1.Bind(record)
        LoadData()
    End Sub
```

[image: DATAGRIDVIEW BEFORE DOUBLE CLICK]

[image: DATAGRIDVIEW AFTER DOUBLE CLICK]

Here's [a link] google drive video so as to understand what I mean (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mGM9z5GjSP5MGvaDgZBRCu2Lfhqx-XGi/view?usp=share_link)!

Comment: Why do you call `LoadData()` in the DoubleClick handler?

Comment: @djv , thank you for your response provided a solution for me